# Drupal 8 php coding standards error: Namespaced classes/interfaces/traits should be referenced with use statements

Tags: php, drupal-8

I'm working on a Drupal 8 custom module that renders an image in a block. The following lines are being flagged by codesniffer:

```
$advertFile = \Drupal\file\Entity\File::load($advert1);
$advertStyle = \Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle::load('ad_banner')->buildUrl($advertFile->getFileUri());
```

The error being generated is:

> Namespaced classes/interfaces/traits should be referenced with use
>   statements

I've placed the following use statements at the top of the file and altered the lines to File::load... and ImageStyle::load... respectively. This throws errors and the site stops working.

Not quiet sure how to express namespaced classes correctly in a custom D8 module, so any help appreciated!

Update:
The top of the file looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Block;

/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Block\AdvertBlock.
 */

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;
use Drupal\image\Plugin\Field\FieldWidget\ImageWidget;
use Drupal\image\Entity\ImageStyle;
```

The error message I am getting is: 'The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.'

Thanks

Comment: Maybe show the `use` statements. Not jumping out at me.

Comment: `This throws errors and the site stops working.` perhaps telling what those errors are might be a good idea?  Also namespaces come before use statements, so if your file is a namespaced class itself, don't put the `use statements at the top of the file` put it after the namespace